# calling JS function from orientdb through java API

Tags: javascript, java, function, api, orientdb

I'm trying to call a custom JS function stored in OrientDB, from Java, through the OrientDB Java API.

I can use the function inside studio, and it works as expected.

This is the code used to connect to the db and get the function:

```
OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory(SERVER_URL, "user", "pass");
OrientGraph txGraph = factory.getTx();
OFunction functionObject = txGraph.getRawGraph().getMetadata()
.getFunctionLibrary().getFunction("functionName");
```

The problem is that the functionObject returned is null, and inspecting the `getFunctionLibrary()` result, I can see the list of functions is empty.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Using the official [Documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Functions.html#usage-via-java-api) example, gives the same null result.

LE: For anyone stumbling on this, the full working code is:

```
OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory(SERVER_URL, "user", "pass");
OrientGraph txGraph = factory.getTx();
Double response = (Double) txGraph.command(new OCommandFunction("functionName")).execute(functionParameter);
```

where `response` is the result the function gives and `functionParameter`is a parameter I'm passing to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for java functions only (and example in doc is correct because it retrieves java function). 
In order to execute js/sql/whatever function use OCommandFunction. Something like this:

```
txGraph.command(new OCommandFunction("functionName")).execute()
```

Possibly it could work directly too (if you don't need to convert result to graph objects)

```
new OCommandFunction("functionName").execute()
```

But in this case db instance must be attached to thread (db connection object created before function call)